# What were the characteristics of the Apollo Skylab CSM white paint?

Tags: apollo-program, spacecraft, materials, skylab

The Apollo Skylab CSM had painted white surfaces as well as polished aluminum ones. Was this paint applyed over the aluminum, or was there any surfacing ( a primer? ) to ensure that the white paint would adhere to the metal? Is there any study on the performance of this kind of paint during the longest Skylab mission (89 days)? Is this a paint, in the strict sense of the word?[image: Apollo white pattern]

Answer (score 5):

The paint, as can be seen from [this article](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2003DPS....35.3602J/abstract), contains a titanium-oxide semiconductor. The spectral measurements of the paint are similar for J002E3 as they were from measurements taken shortly after launch, showing that the paint still performs well even after over 30 years in orbit, for the Apollo 12 mission. The paint simply serves as a thermal control mechanism. From [this news article](https://web.archive.org/web/20170310022023/http://archives.chicagotribune.com/1969/07/05/page/9/article/order-a-new-paint-job-on-apollo-rocket/), we can see that a primer was used (And apparently, the wrong primer was used for at least one rocket)